# CUDA atomicAdd being run too many times

Tags: python, cuda

I am trying to initialise a numpy matrix with a preset initial cache size, and then each CUDA thread with run atomicAdd at most once, hopefully as long as the accumulated sum is still within the initial cache size.

The problem here is that when the initial cache size (500) is smaller than the number of threads (1024), it returns with very unexpected number that the accumulated sum becomes very large (1140850688).

Could anyone kindly advise why it does not work?  or how to make it works?  Ideally I would like the "if (result_count[0] < InitialResultCacheSize - 1)" to stop atomicAdd from accumulating to over the initial cache size (InitialResultCacheSize).

```
import os

_path = r"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\Hostx64\x64"

if os.system("cl.exe"):
    os.environ['PATH'] += ';' + _path
if os.system("cl.exe"):
    raise RuntimeError("cl.exe still not found, path probably incorrect")

import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

RESULT_COLUMN_COUNT = 4

InitialResultCacheSize = 10000
# InitialResultCacheSize = 500

number_matrix = np.zeros(InitialResultCacheSize * RESULT_COLUMN_COUNT)
number_matrix = number_matrix.astype(np.float32)

number_matrix_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(number_matrix.nbytes)
cuda.memcpy_htod(number_matrix_gpu, number_matrix)

result_count = np.int32(0)
result_count_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(result_count.nbytes)
cuda.memcpy_htod(result_count_gpu, result_count)

mod = SourceModule("""
  #include <cstdlib>

    __global__ void test_cuda_utilisation(int InitialResultCacheSize, int RESULT_COLUMN_COUNT, float *number_matrix, int *result_count)
  {
     int result_index, result_index_offset;
     
     if (result_count[0] < InitialResultCacheSize - 1) {
       result_index = atomicAdd(result_count,1);
       result_index_offset = result_index * RESULT_COLUMN_COUNT;
       number_matrix[result_index_offset + 0] = result_index;
       number_matrix[result_index_offset + 1] = result_count[0];
       number_matrix[result_index_offset + 2] = InitialResultCacheSize;
       number_matrix[result_index_offset + 3] = RESULT_COLUMN_COUNT;
     }
  }
  """)
      
func = mod.get_function("test_cuda_utilisation")
func(np.int32(InitialResultCacheSize), np.int32(RESULT_COLUMN_COUNT), number_matrix_gpu, result_count_gpu, block=(4,16,16))

result_count_out = np.empty_like(result_count)
cuda.memcpy_dtoh(result_count_out, result_count_gpu)
print('result_count_out = ' + str(result_count_out) + ' and InitialResultCacheSize is ' + str(InitialResultCacheSize))

number_matrix_out = np.empty((result_count_out, RESULT_COLUMN_COUNT), dtype=np.float32)
cuda.memcpy_dtoh(number_matrix_out, number_matrix_gpu)

print('number_matrix_out is with len ' + str(len(number_matrix_out)) + ' x ' + str(len(number_matrix_out[0])))
print(number_matrix_out)
```

Result of InitialResultCacheSize = 10000

```
'cl.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.33.31629 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

result_count_out = 1024 and InitialResultCacheSize is 10000
number_matrix_out is with len 1024 x 4
[[0.000e+00 1.024e+03 1.000e+04 4.000e+00]
 [1.000e+00 1.024e+03 1.000e+04 4.000e+00]
 [2.000e+00 1.024e+03 1.000e+04 4.000e+00]
 ...
 [1.021e+03 1.024e+03 1.000e+04 4.000e+00]
 [1.022e+03 1.024e+03 1.000e+04 4.000e+00]
 [1.023e+03 1.024e+03 1.000e+04 4.000e+00]]
```

Result of InitialResultCacheSize = 500

```
'cl.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.33.31629 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

result_count_out = 1140850688 and InitialResultCacheSize is 500
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File C:\PythonProjects\TradeAnalysis\Test\TestCUDAUtilisation.py:67 in <module>
    cuda.memcpy_dtoh(number_matrix_out, number_matrix_gpu)

LogicError: cuMemcpyDtoH failed: invalid argument
```

Trial on another approach, not sure if it is the legal behaviour approach

```
import os

# _path = r"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\Hostx64\x64"
_path = r"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\Hostx64\x64"
# _path = r"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\Hostx64"
# _path = r"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\Hostx64\x64\"

if os.system("cl.exe"):
    os.environ['PATH'] += ';' + _path
if os.system("cl.exe"):
    raise RuntimeError("cl.exe still not found, path probably incorrect")

import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

RESULT_COLUMN_COUNT = 4

# InitialResultCacheSize = 10000
InitialResultCacheSize = 500


number_matrix = np.zeros(InitialResultCacheSize * RESULT_COLUMN_COUNT)
number_matrix = number_matrix.astype(np.float32)

number_matrix_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(number_matrix.nbytes)
cuda.memcpy_htod(number_matrix_gpu, number_matrix)

result_count = 0

mod = SourceModule("""
  #include <cstdlib>

    __global__ void test_cuda_utilisation(int InitialResultCacheSize, int RESULT_COLUMN_COUNT, int result_count, float *number_matrix)
  {
     int result_index, result_index_offset;
     
     result_index = atomicAdd(&result_count,1);
     if (result_index < InitialResultCacheSize - 1) {
       result_index_offset = result_index * RESULT_COLUMN_COUNT;
       number_matrix[result_index_offset + 0] = result_index;
       number_matrix[result_index_offset + 1] = result_count;
       number_matrix[result_index_offset + 2] = InitialResultCacheSize;
       number_matrix[result_index_offset + 3] = RESULT_COLUMN_COUNT;
     }
  }
  """)
      
func = mod.get_function("test_cuda_utilisation")
func(np.int32(InitialResultCacheSize), np.int32(RESULT_COLUMN_COUNT), np.int32(result_count), number_matrix_gpu, block=(4,16,16))

print('result_count = ' + str(result_count) + ' and InitialResultCacheSize = ' + str(InitialResultCacheSize))
```

which result with the below.  Still cannot get the count of how many times atomicAdd has been run

```
result_count = 0 and InitialResultCacheSize = 500
```

Comment: This sort of design doesn't work in a massively multithreaded environment (CUDA).   You have many threads that can all read `result_count[0]` **at the same time**, so they will all observe that it is less than the limit.  They will all then proceed into the body of the if statement, and they will all perform the `atomicAdd`.  Clearly, if enough threads do this, you haven't limited the value in `result_count[0]` from "overflow".  You may be able to "fix" it by simply doing the `atomicAdd` first, and then do your if-check on that, i.e., `if (result_index < InitialResultCacheSize - 1)`

Comment: Then when you read the value out of `result_count[0]` later (e.g. in host code, copy D2H), you must adjust your code such that if the observed value is greater than `InitialResultCacheSize`, that you clamp it to `InitialResultCacheSize`.

Comment: My first question here is that while my C++ code there does not have looping, and I run it with 1024 threads, I would expect at most each thread run atomicAdd once, which means atomicAdd is at most run in total 1024 times.  Why when I set InitialResultCacheSize = 500, the result_count_out is more than 1024?

Comment: well, your device code is writing beyond the end of the allocated array, correct?  Who knows what values it is overwriting when that happens?  You have to get rid of the illegal behavior in your code before you can try to make sense of the outputs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation.  Could you help to educate me what the legal behavior practice for atomicAdd in the code is?  I put a trial on another approach in the code above but the result_count fail to return how many times the atomicAdd has been run.  How should it be to be a proper code for atomicAdd?  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You changed several things, most incorrectly (e.g. you cannot do atomics on a local variable, you are not actually copying any results back to the host, etc.) in between your first and second postings, more than just the one thing I suggested you change.

If we start with your first listing, here are the changes I suggest to address the usage of atomics:

```
$ cat t35.py
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import numpy as np

RESULT_COLUMN_COUNT = 4

InitialResultCacheSize = 500

number_matrix = np.zeros(InitialResultCacheSize * RESULT_COLUMN_COUNT)
number_matrix = number_matrix.astype(np.float32)

number_matrix_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(number_matrix.nbytes)
cuda.memcpy_htod(number_matrix_gpu, number_matrix)

result_count = np.zeros(1, dtype=np.int32)
result_count_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(result_count.nbytes)
cuda.memcpy_htod(result_count_gpu, result_count)

mod = SourceModule("""
  #include <cstdlib>

    __global__ void test_cuda_utilisation(int InitialResultCacheSize, int RESULT_COLUMN_COUNT, float *number_matrix, int *result_count)
  {
     int result_index, result_index_offset;
     result_index = atomicAdd(result_count, 1);
     if (result_index < InitialResultCacheSize - 1) {
       result_index_offset = result_index * RESULT_COLUMN_COUNT;
       number_matrix[result_index_offset + 0] = result_index;
       number_matrix[result_index_offset + 1] = result_count[0];
       number_matrix[result_index_offset + 2] = InitialResultCacheSize;
       number_matrix[result_index_offset + 3] = RESULT_COLUMN_COUNT;
     }
  }
  """)

func = mod.get_function("test_cuda_utilisation")
func(np.int32(InitialResultCacheSize), np.int32(RESULT_COLUMN_COUNT), number_matrix_gpu, result_count_gpu, block=(4,16,16))

result_count_out = np.empty_like(result_count)
cuda.memcpy_dtoh(result_count_out, result_count_gpu)
print('result_count_out = ' + str(result_count_out) + ' and InitialResultCacheSize is ' + str(InitialResultCacheSize))
if InitialResultCacheSize < result_count_out:
    result_count_out = InitialResultCacheSize
number_matrix_out = np.empty((result_count_out, RESULT_COLUMN_COUNT), dtype=np.float32)
cuda.memcpy_dtoh(number_matrix_out, number_matrix_gpu)

print('number_matrix_out is with len ' + str(len(number_matrix_out)) + ' x ' + str(len(number_matrix_out[0])))
print(number_matrix_out)
$ python t35.py
result_count_out = [1024] and InitialResultCacheSize is 500
number_matrix_out is with len 500 x 4
[[  0.00000000e+00   1.02400000e+03   5.00000000e+02   4.00000000e+00]
 [  1.00000000e+00   1.02400000e+03   5.00000000e+02   4.00000000e+00]
 [  2.00000000e+00   1.02400000e+03   5.00000000e+02   4.00000000e+00]
 ...,
 [  4.97000000e+02   1.02400000e+03   5.00000000e+02   4.00000000e+00]
 [  4.98000000e+02   1.02400000e+03   5.00000000e+02   4.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]]
$
```

You'll note that the reported output of the atomic variable is 1024, but since there are only 500 "slots" available for output, we are limiting ourselves (both in kernel/device code, and in your host code) to the number of output slots available.

So 1024 atomic ops were done, one per thread, because you are launching 1024 threads.  But we are limiting the kernel to only write to 500 rows of output, because that's all that are allocated.  Likewise, when retrieving results to the host, we must acknowledge that if the reported number of atomic ops is larger than the `InitialResultCacheSize`, then we must limit ourselves to the lower number.